# Is it possible to do WebRTC within Local Network from Pc to Pc with no use of Internet Access?

Tags: php, webrtc

Hi we are working on something today with webRTC, and our objective is only peer to peer access with not much use of Internet Access. We had this idea that the API will also be needing an Internet Access, yet our main agenda with the voice call it will not use much of Internet Access. We all know that data consumption of VoiceData would really be an issue if the Internet Speed would not be sufficient. Thats why we had this idea of WebRTC of peer to peer access within LAN Network only.

But sad to say there are no documentation that fits to our objective. this type of concept is very easy with VB but we were hoping to to this on a Browser.

Is there anyone who can give us a highlight on this?
Thanks

Comment: If you need only voice data to be transmitted then navigator.getUserMedia( {audio:true}.... ) will help you... check this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ and this http://updates.html5rocks.com/tag/getusermedia .. hope it will fulfill your objetive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use WebRTC inside your local network without an access to Internet. You don't need to use any special tricks to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use WebRTC on LAN. But you will require a signaling server that is inside your LAN network so that you can exchange the WebRTC SDP offer, answer and ICE candidates between your browser clients.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have noted that you can run a signaling server within the LAN.  This is true, however, this all depends on the fact that both machines can see each other, which is not always possible in all LAN setups.

It is also possible to use a signaling server that is on the Internet.  If in fact the browsers are able to talk to each other then they will and the only data that will hit the Internet is signaling traffic that is used to set things up.  All the media (audio, video) should go over the LAN.  In most cases, the signaling data is tiny, so if your goal is to minimize data usage, not eliminate it entirely, this should be good enough.

If you want to make sure that you aren't sending audio out over the Internet, first check that the two machines are able to see each other (ping should be able to tell you this).  To be really sure, you can see where the packets are going with a tool like Wireshark.